# Will purchasing the 'Elite Dangerous: Horizons' DLC from Steam cause conflicts?

Tags: steam, elite-dangerous, elite-dangerous-horizons

**Background:**

So back when *Elite Dangerous* first came out, I purchased the main game from the *Frontier* store.

**Present Day:**

I now wish to purchase the *Elite Dangerous: Horizons* DLC from Steam.

I have seem that on the *Frontier* store you can generate a key to add the *Elite Dangerous* game to your Steam library.

See:
[Can I get a Steam library product code?](https://support.frontier.co.uk/kb/faq.php?id=200) &
[Elite: Dangerous Steam Keys](https://forums.frontier.co.uk/showthread.php/148965-Elite-Dangerous-Steam-Keys).

**Question:**

So now I was wondering, will getting a steam key from the Frontier store allow me to to purchase the  *Elite Dangerous: Horizons* DLC from steam ***without any conflicts?***

Or am I better purchasing from the *Frontier* store again and then porting across to steam after, using the before mentioned keys?

---

***Side Note:***
*I am aware that the current price from both the 
Frontier store (£10) 
and Steam (£9.99)

in the UK is practically the same. However I have been recently given Steam credit which is what I wish to use for this purchase.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no conflict. On Steam, the actual "Elite: Dangerous" title consists of a launcher that is tied to your *Frontier* account. The launcher and Frontier account is what gives you access to the DLC, not Steam. Steam is effectively optional here, since the launcher is where all the magic happens.

The base game you download from Steam includes the Horizons content already, inputting the key you get from Frontier or the Steam store merely unlocks it.

Regardless of where you purchase your key, as long as it's tied to the same Frontier account at the end of the day, it will work in Steam.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when you redeem a key on Steam, Steam treats it is as if you had purchased that game on Steam with money. When another store offers you a steam key, and taking that offer doesn't invalidate your ownership on that store, then you will own the game twice. Once on the original store and once on Steam.

Also note [Steam's refund policy](http://store.steampowered.com/steam_refunds). When you bought a DLC package which doesn't work, you can refund it within 14 days, unless you played the base game for more than 2 hours after purchase.

Comment: Nice mention of Steam's refund policy, I had forgotten about that. Makes it worth taking the risk and fixing it if it doesn't work. :)

Comment: Be careful with DLC - the refund only applies if the underlying title has been played for less than two hours. If you've got more time than that on Elite, it won't let you do it.

Comment: @MikeyT.K. If you played the underlying title for less than two hours **after buying the dlc**.